# Ionic cordova production build fails while using shared components

Tags: angular, cordova, typescript, ionic3, hybrid-mobile-app

I am having path resolution issues while trying to get a production build for an ionic 3 app. I have a SharedComponents folder (at root) which is shared across multiple apps. The shared components' paths are configured in a tsconfig.json file which is kept at root of each app folder (outside src folder). Now, during development build, all paths get resolved correctly and everything works fine. But, when I try to do a production build, it throws a 'Cannot find module' error. It is unable to resolve the shared components' paths from tsconfig.json during production build.

Here is an illustration of the project structure,

```
    root
       - SharedComponents
          - component_1
          - component_2
          - component_3

       - App_1
          - tsconfig.json

       - App_2
          - tsconfig.json
```

These are the CLI commands I am using,

```
    Production build
       ionic cordova build android --prod

    To view the errors
       Step 1: ionic serve
       Step 2: ionic cordova build android --prod
       Step 3: Refresh localhost to view errors in console.

    Note
       1. Run production build only after ionic serve is complete.
       2. Errors are seen only during production build.
```

Versions used,

```
    @angular/core v4.0.2
    ionic-angular v3.1.1
    @ionic/app-scripts v1.3.4
```

Any thoughts on how to resolve this issue? Thank you in advance.